# Plot large data sample (using 1M data from (CSV import))

Tags: flutter, csv, charts, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

**This line of code is working, converting the CSV file to a line chart or bar chart** (the bar chart was commented for a purpose). **The line chart or bar chart can only plot thousands of data points**, like, for example, 32k to 132k, and the plotting of the data has a waiting time of 1 second to 47 seconds, depending on how many data points are going to be plotted in the chart.

For example:

32,768 Data -  1 Second (Line Graph)   07 Seconds (Line and Bar Graph)

65,536 Data -  10 Seconds(Line Graph)  16 Seconds (Line and Bar Graph)

98,304 Data -  14 Seconds(Line Graph)  52 Seconds (Line and Bar Graph)

131,072 Data - 45 Seconds(Line Graph)

However, when I plot 1 million data points, it fails or the flutter does not respond after an hour of waiting. **Is there a way to plot a million pieces of data in Flutter Charts or a half million pieces of data?**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_charts/charts.dart';
// import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:csv/csv.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  // This widget is the root of your application.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  MyHomePageState createState() => MyHomePageState();
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late List<WaveForm> _chartData;
  late List<WaveForm> _barGraphData;
  late TooltipBehavior _tooltipBehavior;

  List<PlatformFile>? _paths;
  ChartSeriesController? _chartSeriesController;
  String? _extension = "csv";
  FileType _pickingType = FileType.custom;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _chartData = [];
    _barGraphData = [];
    _tooltipBehavior = TooltipBehavior(enable: true);
    super.initState();
  }

  openFile(filepath) async {
    File f = File(filepath);
    // print("CSV to List");
    final input = f.openRead();
    final fields = await input
        .transform(utf8.decoder)
        .transform(const CsvToListConverter())
        .toList();

    // _chartData.add(ChartData(3,23));

    // fields.forEach(
    //     (element)
    //     {
    //       _chartData.add(WaveForm(fields.indexOf(element), element[0]));

    //     }
    //   );
    // //Passed the necessary arguments to the updateDataSource method. Here passed the added and removed data point indexes.
    // _chartSeriesController?.updateDataSource(
    //   addedDataIndexes: <int>[_chartData.length - 1],
    // );

    setState(() {
      _chartData.clear();

      fields.forEach((element) {
        _chartData.add(WaveForm(fields.indexOf(element), element[0]));
      });
    });
    //   // for (var n in fields) {
    //   //   _chartData.add(WaveForm(fields.indexOf(n), n[0]));
    //   // }

    //   _barGraphData = _chartData;
    // });
  }

  void clearWaveform() async {
    _chartData.clear();
  }

  void _pickFile() async {
    try {
      _paths = (await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
        type: _pickingType,
        allowMultiple: false,
        allowedExtensions: (_extension?.isNotEmpty ?? false)
            ? _extension?.replaceAll(' ', '').split(',')
            : null,
      ))
          ?.files;
    }
    // } on PlatformException catch (e) {
    //   print("Unsupported operation" + e.toString());
    catch (ex) {
      // print(ex);
    }
    if (!mounted) return;
    setState(() {
      openFile(_paths![0].path);
      // print(_paths);
      // print("File path ${_paths![0]}");
      // print(_paths!.first.extension);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text('PowerHouse'),
              actions: [
                //actions widget in appbar
                IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.radio_button_on),
                    onPressed: () {
                      //code to execute when this button is pressed
                    }),

                IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
                    onPressed: () {
                      //code to execute when this button is pressed
                    }),

                IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.upload_file),
                    onPressed: () {
                      //code to execute when this button is pressed
                      _pickFile();
                    }),

                IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.clear),
                    onPressed: () {
                      clearWaveform();
                    }),
                //more widgets to place here
              ],
            ),
            body: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: SfCartesianChart(
                    // loadMoreIndicatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, ChartSwipeDirection direction) =>
                    //  getLoadMoreViewBuilder(context, direction),
                    title: ChartTitle(text: 'Sample Line Chart'),
                    legend: Legend(isVisible: true),
                    tooltipBehavior: _tooltipBehavior,
                    series: <FastLineSeries>[
                      FastLineSeries<WaveForm, int>(
                        name: 'Waveform',
                        dataSource: _chartData,
                        // onRendererCreated: (ChartSeriesController controller) {
                        //   _chartSeriesController = controller;
                        // },
                        xValueMapper: (WaveForm value, _) => value.time,
                        yValueMapper: (WaveForm value, _) => value.value,
                        dataLabelSettings:
                            const DataLabelSettings(isVisible: false),
                        enableTooltip: true,
                        color: Colors.orange,
                        width: 2,
                        opacity: 0.8,
                        dashArray: const <double>[5, 5],
                        // splineType: SplineType.cardinal,
                        // cardinalSplineTension: 0.9
                      )
                    ],
                    primaryXAxis: NumericAxis(
                      edgeLabelPlacement: EdgeLabelPlacement.shift,
                    ),
                    primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(
                        // labelFormat: '{value}M',
                        // numberFormat: NumberFormat.(decimalDigits: 0)
                        ),
                  ),
                ),
                // Expanded(
                //     child: SfCartesianChart(
                //         title: ChartTitle(text: 'Sample Bar Chart'),
                //         legend: Legend(isVisible: true),
                //         isTransposed: true,
                //         series: <ChartSeries>[
                //       BarSeries<WaveForm, int>(
                //           name: 'Bar Chart',
                //           dataSource: _chartData,
                //           xValueMapper: (WaveForm data, _) => data.time,
                //           yValueMapper: (WaveForm data, _) => data.value,
                //           // Width of the bars
                //           width: 0.6,
                //           // Spacing between the bars
                //           spacing: 0.3)
                //     ]))
              ],
            )));
  }

  // Widget getLoadMoreViewBuilder(
  //     BuildContext context, ChartSwipeDirection direction) {
  //      if (direction == ChartSwipeDirection.end) {
  //        return FutureBuilder<String>(
  //          future: _updateData(), /// Adding data by updateDataSource method
  //          builder:
  //           (BuildContext futureContext, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapShot) {
  //            return snapShot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done
  //                ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
  //                : SizedBox.fromSize(size: Size.zero);
  //           },
  //        );
  //      } else {
  //        return SizedBox.fromSize(size: Size.zero);
  //      }
  //   }
}

// class SalesData {
//   SalesData(this.year, this.sales);
//   final double year;
//   final double sales;
// }

class WaveForm {
  WaveForm(this.time, this.value);
  final int time;
  final int value;
}
```

Since I can't upload the CSV file here, here's the 1 million rows from the CSV file. Minimal data from 100k below is working and plotting from the line or bar chart, but when I try to plot the 1 million data from the chart it won't work or the flutter does not respond even after an hour of waiting. 
[image: 1M Data]

Here's the sample of thousands of data plotted in the line chart.
[image: Simulation with thousands of Data]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use isolates and try to split the reading of the dataset in multiple threads or you can get the data processed from the backend